# How to enable experimental rounded corners?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, metacity

My one major disappointment with Oneiric is that it no longer includes nice rounded corners as in some of the dev builds:
[Andrea Cimitan's Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/107658363031614745288/posts/1XaLyXPdaQ6).

Although he argues that Compiz is still too buggy to make it work, I still want to try it out. Does anyone know what packages I need to install/compile to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

There was (possibly still is) a PPA for this, but it did not work for me when I had tested it (compiz would crash). Fortunately these borders will be in 12.04, and may be backported before then (to my understanding).

I will update my answer if I find any changes to the state of the situation.